# How to make a margin-top percentage update automatically?

Tags: html, css, margin

In this page ([Mozilla Developer Network: margin-top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-top?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/margin-top)), it mentions a percentage working for the `margin-top` CSS property. This does work correctly, but the only issue is that it doesn't update when the parent element is stretched until the page is refreshed. How can I make it so it will update the margin without refreshing?

I've put up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kX7GY/1/).

Comment: javascript or jQuery.

Comment: That doesn't sound right... do you have an example or Fiddle? The idea behind using a percentage value instead of a fixed pixel value is having the benefit of dynamic scaling.

Comment: how is the parent element being stretched? give us a fiddle

Comment: It's just a simple div that stretches because of the browser resizing. Fiddle is now in the question.

Comment: dont want to be "that guy" but your fiddle seem to work fine on my computer. Im using firefox 29

Comment: It does work fine in Firefox. Is this an IE bug then? Was using IE 11 on Windows 8.1 before.